# Switching Academic Fields for Grad Admission - Europe and Australia

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, europe, changing-fields, australia

I am a pre-final year Electronics and Communication Engineering Undergraduate. I am very much interested in pursuing higher studies in Radio Astronomy and am working on multiple projects in a specific area with a collaboration. I had a brief chat with my project supervisor on applying for higher studies in the same area due to my interest development and he strongly recommended a few Institutions in Europe (UK, Netherlands, Germany) and Australia.

My question is: I have heard it is very difficult switching academic fields (in my case, from engineering to physics) while applying for graduate admissions in these countries and acceptance rate in such a case is very less inspite of having relevant research experience and publications. Please let me know if this is true, and if so, what can be done to mitigate this.

Would really appreciate any help :)

Comment: a good letter of recommendation helps, and you seem to have someone supporting you who could write such a letter.